# Which is the most recommended syntax for attaching Vue object to an element?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

When attaching an instance of Vue to a HTML element, I can do in two ways.

1. By property reference, *el:"#rooty"*
2. By method call, *$mount("#rooty")*

I can't decide between them. Are they precisely equivalent? If one is newer or obsolete'ish, which one is recommended? Is there any other difference and in such case, what would it be?

By property reference.

```
const app = new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  el: "#rooty",
  ...
});//.$mount("#rooty");
```

By method call.

```
const app = new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  //el: "#rooty",
  ...
}).$mount("#rooty");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it seems from the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount), purpose of `$mount()` is to have an unmounted vue instance and mount it later. From the docs:

> If a Vue instance didn’t receive the el option at instantiation, it will be in “unmounted” state, without an associated DOM element. vm.$mount() can be used to manually start the mounting of an unmounted Vue instance.

---

I believe `el:"#rooty"` is just a syntactic sugar provided to users over `$mount` as internally `$mount` is used to attach an instance to HTML element. see the code below from [vue repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/d2f7f1913edadda57e9a386dde08df226b29fa1f/src/core/instance/render.js#L42):

```
export function initRender (vm: Component) {
  ...
  ...
  // bind the createElement fn to this instance
  // so that we get proper render context inside it.
  // args order: tag, data, children, needNormalization, alwaysNormalize
  // internal version is used by render functions compiled from templates
  vm._c = (a, b, c, d) => createElement(vm, a, b, c, d, false)
  // normalization is always applied for the public version, used in
  // user-written render functions.
  vm.$createElement = (a, b, c, d) => createElement(vm, a, b, c, d, true)
  if (vm.$options.el) {
    vm.$mount(vm.$options.el)
  }
}
```

Comment: True, I've seen that passage too. Perhaps I'm wording the question inappropriately. Should I aim at not having unmounted instances? Should I try to achieve the opposite? Does it matter? Is there any significance? What's likely to be most common? I have my opinion but it's based on C# and configurations from there.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I don't think it matters, what matters is do you have some use-case of unmounted instance where you want to mount same component on different HTML elements. I have updated my answer, it seems vue internally uses `$mount` to mount a component, `$el` is for convenience of users, as it is always easy to pass a hash.